# Display log file in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, console-output

I need to display a log file (which is present in a test machine), in the **console output** of a Jenkins job that I run.
Is that possible? 
If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select execute Windows batch command or Execute Shell based on your requirement

then use "cat log.file" (linux)
"type log.file" (windows) to display

Comment: what if I need to do something like `ping www.google.com -t 1>a.txt 2>&1 | type a.txt`. I mean the file is continuously being written, and I want to display it in the console at the same time.