# Grab text output and put it in build output?

Tags: logging, jenkins

I hav ea build project in jenkins, one of my tools only logs to a provided text file.

The output to the log file is done in real time so you can keep seeing updates as you refresh.

Is there a way in Jenkins to grab that output and put it in the build output?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31470472/display-log-file-in-jenkins